# Adwords to Big Query Data Transfer Service does not report the same values as Adwords Manager

Tags: google-bigquery, google-ads-api, data-transfer

I'm using the data transfer service to gather adwords data for various accounts we manage, this data gets stored in big query in a number of different tables.

At the ad level, querying the "AdBasicStats" table, I notice there are clicks and costs that don't appear in adwords. I am unable to replicate the AdBasicStats table in adwords reports as most of the fields are not available to me.

This is usually a click per ad on a given day, which attributes a small cost, but when aggregate up to a campaign level over a few days these costs are completely different to what adwords is telling me,

I have brought this is up with adwords support with specific examples and I've yet to hear back and this was over 3 weeks ago.

I was wondering if any one else was having a similar issue, or knows what could be the reason for the discrepancy between the platforms.

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks,
Ryan

EDIT [an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiWuW.png)

Comment: We don't use AdWords, but we use the DFP transfer service. There will always be a discrepancies between the platform reporting and the raw level data you get in BigQuery. I remember our account manager telling us to factor in a 5% discrepancy at some stage. In the docs, it's stated ~1% but we see it varying. https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/1733124?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Check the 'invalid clicks' column under campaign view in the UI. If invalid clicks + total clicks = the sum of clicks in the AdBasicStats table then this could be the reason.

I am not sure how Data Transfer Service works, but it might be worth exploring if a lookback window is set when upserting data to BQ. I have observed 100% match rates (AdWords UI against API) with a 30 day lookback window.

There is an opensource project available to extract AdWords data - https://github.com/googleads/aw-reporting however it does not currently support BigQuery.

For a paid service I would recommend https://www.xplenty.com. Supports many platform and a BigQuery integration.

Comment: Thanks for you help, it looks like these invalid clicks are the cause of this problem, I have set the refresh window for 30 days so hopefully my bigquery tables will get updated should google deem some of clicks invalid.

It seems I can only see invalid clicks at the campaign level, and not any further, such as the ad group level, do you know why this is?

Comment: Unfortunately invalid clicks are only available at the campaign level. To ensure data consistency I would recommend to setting the refresh for all report types. Since we are on the the subject of data quality, here's a tip which may help -  we have found issues when a user changes a campaign name. If campaign ID 123 was named "brand" in the year 2017 and then in 2018 it was renamed as "brand+generics" then filtering can be an issue due to 2 campaign names and one campaign ID. For this we use a lookup table which gets refreshed daily then join these 2 tables. Please dont forget to up vote!

Comment: The lookup table is just a complete refresh of all campaigns/adgroup from beginning of time. The table gets overwritten daily and no segmentation is required as we are only interested in the unique campaign names and IDs.